# Using Renderer2 in Angular 5 to output angular directives

Tags: angular

I am currently attempting to create a menu in Angular 5 that I can load from the database. The existing menu looks something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 14px;">
   <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" *ngIf="isAdmin">
       <a [routerLink]="['/fetch-data']">
          <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o"></i>
          <div>Fetch data</div>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I haven't loaded the data in just yet - I'm trying to prove that it can do everything I want first.

I have created a component, for which I intend to build the menu. What I was hoping to do was to produce all the current behaviour of the existing menu, but from within my component. That code is here:

```
import { Component, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-menu",
    template: ""
})
export class MyMenuComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private readonly renderer: Renderer2, private readonly el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const ul = this.renderer.createElement("ul");
        this.renderer.addClass(ul, "nav");
        this.renderer.addClass(ul, "navbar-nav");
        this.renderer.addClass(ul, "navbar-padding");

        const li = this.renderer.createElement("li");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(li, "routerLinkActive", "link-active");

        const a = this.renderer.createElement("a");
        this.renderer.setAttribute(a, "routerLink", "/fetch-data");

        const i = this.renderer.createElement("i");
        this.renderer.addClass(i, "fa");
        this.renderer.addClass(i, "fa-birthday-cake");
        this.renderer.appendChild(a, i);

        const div = this.renderer.createElement("div");
        const text = this.renderer.createText("Fetch data");
        this.renderer.appendChild(div,text);
        this.renderer.appendChild(a, div);

        this.renderer.appendChild(li, a);
        this.renderer.appendChild(ul, li);

        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, ul);
    }

}
```

The issue is that when I generate the routerLinkActive and routerLink attributes, they don't actually work. That is, they haven't been processed as angular attributes. How do I get them to be recognised as angular attributes so that when I click them it takes me to the correct route?

Comment: That's expected because HTML needs to be compiled, this article will help you understand the problem [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get something going, but I don't think it's AOT ready.

Comment: why do you need to build HTML dynamically?

Comment: So I can control the menu items that are displayed from the database.

Comment: take a look at the [angular-universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal), maybe you can setup all that building and compilation stuff on the server side